# Are this ceiling fan and this smart fan control switch compatible?

Tags: ceiling-fan, smart-switch

I'm looking at [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/CARRO-Locus-Smart-Wi-Fi-Ceiling-Fan-Wall-Switch-1-Gang-Works-with-Alexa-Google-Home-and-Siri-Shortcut-HPN-04F02D-WH01/321806221?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&srsltid=AfmBOopP8_RPGXAWEFerpjCmWsaR-8O_PYXVlnKKGTE6k_MVrTG6M_EYp_4) smart ceiling fan switch described, in part, as

> Universal fit: easily turn your existing AC ceiling fan into a smart device with our universal smart switch and the best of all, no hub required, can replace any existing wall switches for your AC ceiling fans

> CARRO Locus Smart Wi-Fi Ceiling Fan Wall Switch (1-Gang), Works with Alexa, Google Home and Siri Shortcut

and [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Windward-IV-52-in-Indoor-LED-Brushed-Nickel-Ceiling-Fan-with-Dimmable-Light-Kit-Remote-Control-and-Reversible-Motor-26663/301163154) ceiling fan described in an info box as "Motor Type AC"

> Windward IV 52 in. Indoor LED Brushed Nickel Ceiling Fan with Dimmable Light Kit, Remote Control and Reversible Motor

(I can't find the model number in the listings) Are these kinds of smart switches *really* compatible with *any* AC motor fan, or are there gotchas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear not to be compatible.  The Carro switch says it is not compatible with fans that have built-in remote control systems, which the Windward fan has.

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you. If it didn't have the control, it would be compatible, right?

Comment: Probably.  Apparently.  Maybe....  depending on whether it met the controller's other requirements, which seem to be pretty common features of all but smart vans and those with wireless remotes.  (Some of the remotes - we have one - look like wall switches and mount in the old wall box that housed the old wall switch.  But it is wireless and has a 9 volt battery that needs replacement every couple of years.)